# Wordpress wp_query custom post type query not working on second page

Tags: wordpress, conflict, custom-post-type

Using below code i'm listing all posts under custom post type **people**

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'people', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value',  'meta_key' => 'wpcf-people-sort-order','posts_per_page' => 4, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
                ); ?>
<div>Title: <?PHP the_title(); ?></div>
<div>Description: <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $postid, 'wpcf-people-desscription', true ) ); ?> </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Below is my pagination,

```
<div class="cus-pagi">
                    <?php
                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                     echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
                    ) );
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Also i created a plugin using above code to display list of titles in sidebar. So whenever i access mysite.com/people both(i.e list of custom posts with pagination & sidebar list of post title) of my custom query are working fine.

If i go to second page, sidebar is showing empty.

did anyone know where i'm going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You you need to use [**the Loop**](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) with your custom query:

```
<?php 
$loop = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'people', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',  
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-people-sort-order',
    'posts_per_page' => 4, 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
  ); 
if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<div>Title: <?PHP the_title(); ?></div>
<div>Description: <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $postid, 'wpcf-people-desscription', true ) ); ?> </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I followed your steps on cystom template and sidebar plugin too but unfortunately it's not working. I have added my pagination codes too. I thought something is wrong with that.